# How to wait for partial element attribute value in Katalon Studio

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, katalon-studio

My app uses traffic-light styled images to report success of message sending back to the user.

HTML of the images is something like this:

```
<img src="images/green.gif" border="0" style="width: 15px; height: 15px; position: relative; left: -1px; top: 1px;">
<img src="images/orange.gif" border="0" style="width: 15px; height: 15px; position: relative; left: -1px; top: 1px;">
<img src="images/red.gif" border="0" style="width: 15px; height: 15px; position: relative; left: -1px; top: 1px;">
```

So, when you click a button that sends the message, the image remains orange for a while and then changes to either red or green.

However, although "images/green.gif" is the source attribute shown in Chrome Dev Tools, when I hover over the element I can see that the full src is something like "https://myapp.com/production/images/green.gif" where the first part of the URL changes depending on the server used.

Now, I would like to do this in Katalon Studio script:

```
TestObject myTestObject = new TestObject('My test object').addProperty('css', ConditionType.EQUALS, '.some-class-name img')
WebUI.waitForElementAttributeValue(myTestObject, 'src', 'images/green.gif', 30)
```

However, Katalon will see the 'src' attribute of the image with the full name so this will timeout after 30 seconds.

Is there a way to wait until the attribute contains a certain string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there is no regex support in  `WebUI.waitForElementAttributeValue` method.

But you can add that condition in css directly and use wait until element present.

```
TestObject myTestObject = new TestObject('My test object').addProperty('css', ConditionType.EQUALS, ".some-class-name img[src='images/green.gif']")
WebUI.waitForElementPresent(myTestObject, 30)
```

or simply as

```
TestObject myTestObject = new TestObject('My test object').addProperty('css', ConditionType.EQUALS, ".some-class-name img[src*='green']")
WebUI.waitForElementPresent(myTestObject, 30)
```